# Generate a random image from a group of images in C# Windows Store App Development

Tags: c#, windows, image, random

I've been trying to generate a random image from a group of specified images with their own locations. I haven't tried any code yet, because I can't find any suitable one.

More specifically, my images are named "orb1, orb2, orb3... orb18". orb2-18 are set invisible. I want one of them to appear randomly at their specified positions when orb1 is pressed. I've sorted out the press function of an image so that's not a problem.

Here's my code :

```
   public Beginner1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        orb2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb5.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb6.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb7.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb8.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb9.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb10.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb11.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb12.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb13.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb14.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb15.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb16.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb17.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        orb18.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }







    private void o1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o12(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o3(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o11(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o9(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o16(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o10(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o18(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o17(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o15(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o14(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o13(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o8(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o7(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o6(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o5(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o4(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void o2(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void scores_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }



}
```

I do not have any errors in this code, it's all fine.

So basically, I want some help with making a random orb visible from those 18 orbs when orb1 is pressed.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a random number provider and create a method that makes a random orb appear:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void showRandomOrb()
{
    switch(rnd.Next(2,19)) // selects random integer from 2 to 18
    {
        case 2:
            orb2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        case 3:
            orb3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        case 4:
            orb4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
        // etc..
        case 18:
            orb18.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
    }
}

private void o1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    showRandomOrb();
}
```